# How to implement ordering in DataTables jqueryPlugin?

Tags: spring-mvc, datatables

```
     @RequestMapping(value = "/CustomerData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody String customerData(
                     HttpServletRequest  request,HttpServletResponse response,Model model,
                     @RequestParam(value = "order",required = false, defaultValue = "ASC") String order,
                     @RequestParam(value = "orderBy",required = false, defaultValue = "customerId") String orderBy) throws IOException {

            //Fetch the page number from client
         Integer pageNumber = 0;
            if (null != request.getParameter("iDisplayStart"))
                pageNumber = (Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("iDisplayStart"))/10)+1;     

            //Fetch search parameter
            String searchParameter = request.getParameter("sSearch");
            String orderByVal = request.getParameter("iSortCol_0");
            String orderVal = request.getParameter("sSortDir_0");

            if(!Employee.isEmptyString(orderByVal))
            {
                if(!Employee.isEmptyString(orderVal))
                {
                    order = orderVal;
                }
                else
                {
                    order = "desc";
                }

                if(orderByVal.equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
                    orderBy = "customerId";
                else if(orderByVal.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                    orderBy = "customerName";
                else if(orderByVal.equalsIgnoreCase("2"))
                    orderBy = "phoneNo";
                else if(orderByVal.equalsIgnoreCase("3"))
                    orderBy = "area";
                else if(orderByVal.equalsIgnoreCase("4"))
                    orderBy = "city";
                else
                {
                    orderBy = "customerId";
                    order = "desc";
                }
            }

            //Fetch Page display length
            Integer pageDisplayLength = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("iDisplayLength"));

            Integer record = (pageNumber-1)*pageDisplayLength;
            //Create page list data

            List<Customer> customerList = customerService.getCustomerList(record,pageDisplayLength);

            customerList = getCustomerListBasedOnSearchParameter(searchParameter, customerList);
            customerList = getSortedCustomer(customerList, order,orderBy);
            response.setContentType("application/Json");    

            Integer count= null;

            if(customerList != null && customerList.size() > 0){
                 count=customerList.size();
            }else{
                count=customerService.count();
                customerList = customerService.getCustomerList(record,pageDisplayLength);
            }
            model.addAttribute("order", order);
            model.addAttribute("orderBy", orderBy);

            CustomerJsonObject customerJson=new CustomerJsonObject();
            //Set Total display record
            customerJson.setiTotalDisplayRecords(count);
            //Set Total record
            customerJson.setiTotalRecords(count);
            customerJson.setAaData(customerList);
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
            String json = gson.toJson(customerJson);
            return json;
        }
```

//The above code  is my controller code.
But it is not performing in my project.
Can you please say me the changes in my controller if any wrong.I have tried doing it but its not possible my me.Can i know the solution for it .

```
//I have implemented in the below way but i dont know how to send these values to jsp through json object.

public List<Customer> getSortedCustomer(List<Customer> customerList,
                final String order, final String orderBy) {
            final boolean desc = order.equals("DESC");
            final int sortDirection=desc ? -1:1;
            Collections.sort(customerList, new Comparator<Customer>() {

                @Override
                public int compare(Customer c1, Customer c2) {

                     if (orderBy.equals("customerId")) {
                        return c1.getCustomerId().compareTo(c2.getCustomerId()) * sortDirection;
                    } else if (orderBy.equals("customerName")) {
                        return c1.getCustomerName().compareTo(c2.getCustomerName()) * sortDirection;
                    } else if (orderBy.equals("phoneNo")) {
                        return c1.getPhoneNo().compareTo(c2.getPhoneNo()) * sortDirection;
                    } else if (orderBy.equals("email_Id")) {
                        return c1.getEmail_Id().compareTo(c2.getEmail_Id()) * sortDirection;
                    } else if (orderBy.equals("area")) {
                        return c1.getArea().compareTo(c2.getArea()) * sortDirection;
                    }else if (orderBy.equals("city")) {
                        return c1.getCity().compareTo(c2.getCity()) * sortDirection;
                    }
                    return 0;
                }
            });
            return customerList;
     }
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Is it just the ordering that's not working or is the table not populating at all?

Comment: i have edited the code..Once check again

Comment: Can you answer my question please?

Comment: order is not working..